# How to add a second Twilio SMS channel to a single Microsoft Bot Framework v4 app?

Tags: twilio, botframework, channel

I have a Microsoft Bot Framework v4 bot. It has a Twilio SMS channel. Both work. 
 My goal is to add a second Twilio SMS phone number that points to the same bot.

I wrote the code in the server to read the RecipientId and RecipientName. I want the server to recognize which number the user texted to and respond depending on that data.

I wrote a class (MyBotCredentialProviderStd) which implements ICredentialProvider. It allocates and stores a SimpleCredentialProvider instance and passes calls through to that object. When it receives a IsValidAppIdAsync call it compares the app id to a (for now) static value corresponding to a second bot registration for the same server app. If match, return true.  If not match, call the MS class.  Same for the GetAppPasswordAsync method.

This code works.  I can send text messages to the two Twilio SMS messages. The server reads the target phone number and replies.

Is there a way to do this in the Azure Portal?  Is there a better or simpler approach?

Thanks,

Adam Leffert
www.leffert.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this in the Azure Portal?

Unfortunately, no. Each Web App Bot/Bot Channels Registration can only be associated with one Twilio number.

> Is there a better or simpler approach?

The approach you're using is probably the easiest. The only other viable option that I can think of would be to use the [Twilio SMS API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api). The flow would be something like this:

1. Create a server running the Twilio SMS API code that basically just forwards the messages to the bot via the [DirectLine API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). **User sends a message to this server**
2. To each activity sent to the bot, include the number: `Activity.ChannelData = new { fromNumber: <555-555-5555> }`. **Server forwards the message to the bot**
3. Handle the activity within your bot, and re-attach the `fromNumber` to the bot's outgoing activity so that your Twilio API server knows where to send the outgoing message to. **Bot sends the reply to the server**
4. And then have the Twilio API server send `Activity.Text` to the user. **Server forwards message from bot to user**

Again, the route you're using is likely the easiest to develop and also maintain.